# Menu item name in Keyboard shortcut

Tags: java, action, keyboard-shortcuts, menuitem, netbeans-platform

In my netbeans platform application, I added a keyboard shortcut to a menu item using annotation in my Action class as follows;

```
@ActionReference(path = "Shortcuts", name = "D-N")
```

and it works fine. I want to append this shortcut key hint into my menu item display name.

ex: "New     Ctrl+N" likewise as used in Netbeans GUI.

Is there a easy way to append this into menu name Or do I need to manually append it to menu?

Comment: This is supposed to happen automatically. I was able to reproduce this issue by creating two actions with the same shortcut; the second action overwrote the first's shortcut. Perhaps you should do a "Find in Projects" (Ctrl+Shift+F) to see if the "D-N" shortcut is attached to two different actions.

Comment: Yes, that is what I understood the problem to be. This is supposed to happen automatically. That is, the "Ctrl+N" text is supposed to be appended to the menu item automatically. I confirmed this by creating an action with the `@ActionRegistration` attribute with the same properties that you have in your question. In my test the "Ctrl+N" text is appended to the menu item text.

Comment: @JonathanSpooner, It doesn't comes automatically for me...Seems something goes wrong with me...Thanks Jonathan for your comment

Comment: As I said in my original comment, the only way that I was able to reproduce this issue (the "Ctrl+N" text not being added to the menu item) was to create another action with the same shortcut. When I created this second action the first action no longer had the "Ctrl+N" text added to the menu item.